# Black Mesa suits in the Xen World

Tags: video-games, half-life

Why were there so many Black Mesa radiation suits in the Xen world?

Comment: Picture or it didn't happen ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Black Mesa has been experimenting with teleportation for a long while before the events in Half-Life. There were a lot expeditions to Xen. That's where all those corpses come from.